# Использование библиотечных функций для работы с символьными данными

Tags: c++

Нужна помощь, не знаю как переделать эту программу полностью на библиотечные функции типа :strcpy() strcat() и прочих. Не меняя суть работы программы.

```
/*Ввести с клавиатуры предложение.
        Произвести вставку запятой после слов заканчивающихся на "й".
        Вывести на экран количество таких вставок.*/
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
        #include <conio.h>
        int main ()
        {
        char S1[100]; char S2[100];
        int i=0,j=0,k=0;
        printf("\n Vvedite slova: ");
        gets(S1);

        while (S1[i]!='\0')
        {
            S2[j++]=S1[i++];
            if ((S1[i-1]=='i')&&(S1[i]==' ')){
                S2[j++]=',';
                k++;
            }
        }
        S2[j]='\0';
        printf("\n %s",S2);
        printf("\n %d",k);
        gets(S2);
        }
```

Вот пытался сделать, но не работает и не выдаёт ошибок. Подскажите что поменять.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{int i,m,k;
char str[100];
char *(words[20]);
char newstr[100]="";
gets(str);
m=0;k=0;
char *sp;
sp=strtok(str," ");
while(sp)
{
    words[m++]=sp;
    sp=strtok(NULL," ");
}

for(i=0;i<m;i++)
{
    strcat(newstr,words[i]);
    if(words[i][strlen(words[i])-1]=='i' && words[i][strlen(words[i])]==' ') {
        strcat(newstr,",");
    }
    strcat(newstr," ");
    k++;
}

puts(newstr);
printf("\n %sp",sp);

getchar();
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Vano250696, `strtok()` **меняет** строку (`man strtok`). 

Она заменяет пробел (по ним Вы разбиваете строку на слова) двоичным нулем. Поэтому

    && words[i][strlen(words[i])]==' '

никогда не сработает.

Comment: @Vano250696, уберите

     && words[i][strlen(words[i])]==' '

из `if`.

Читайте `man strtok`.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало.